# Nothing happened after I updating file via FTP, why?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I installed a Ghost Blog on Microsoft Azure, works like a charm.
Then I tried to modify the theme.

I choose the FTP way, and I did it, it worked.

Then strange thing happened.
It only worked once...no more.

After the 1st success,
no matter what I change, nothing happened,
I downloaded the file from the FTP, it was the updated version.

But, why, why it doesn't change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Just need a restart..
It works..